# Extracting values from JSON using JSONPath, excluding specific ones

Tags: json, jsonpath

I've got a JSON like that:

```
[
{
"accID": "3asdasd321asdasdfsadf2",
"test": "one",
"isGood": "true",
},
{
"accID": "Not Found",
"test": "two",
"isGood": "true",
},
{
"accID": "1asdasd121asdasdfsadf5",
"test": "five",
"isGood": "false",
}
]
```

And I want to get all of the **accID** values, but excludeing *'Not Found'* values, like an **example**:

```
[
"3asdasd321asdasdfsadf2",
"1asdasd121asdasdfsadf5"
]
```

I just can't figure out how to setup a filter.

`.accID` returns all of **accID** values in the needed format, but obviously *'Not Found'* is included.

`$.[?(@.accID != 'Not Found')]` - this one returns the almost the same original JSON. *'Not Found'* is excluded from that, but I need only **accID**'s.

I thought that this filter should work `$.accID[?(@.accID != 'Not Found')]` , but it doesn't.

Could someone please tell me the correct filter to get values just like an **example**?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer:

```
$.[?(@.acc != 'Not Found')].acc
```

Thanks anyway.